# Traefik - loadbalancer route traffic to prioritized container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, traefik

given scenario:

1. We want to deploy a static website (generated html files).
2. These files get updated every 3 minutes.
3. Once the files are updated, we can build the new docker image

what we want:

1. A website available with "no downtime" and the most recent content

what are we doing:

1. Two docker compose files that run the image containing the files
2. After successful build we recreate the first compose and after 5 seconds we recreate the second container.

[Traefik View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt5ur.png)

where is the "problem":

1. once the first compose is up again, there are like 1-4 seconds where the content served from these containers is not the same.

**my question:**

**Is there a way to tell traefik to route the traffic a specific container (e.g. the one thats already recreated) if it is available?**

File 1

```
version: '3'
services:
    service1:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: nginx-with-content-foo-bar
        container_name: service-container1
        networks:
           - traefik
        #volumes:
        #  - "./data:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro"
        labels:
            - "traefik.http.routers.my-name.rule=Host(`my-name.foo.bar.de`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.my-name.tls"
            - "traefik.http.routers.my-name.service=my-name"
            - "traefik.http.services.my-name.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

networks:
    traefik:
        external:
            name: traefik
```

File 2

```
version: '3'
services:
    service2:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: nginx-with-content-foo-bar
        container_name: service-container2
        networks:
           - traefik
        #volumes:
        #  - "./data:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro"
        labels:
            - "traefik.http.routers.my-name.rule=Host(`my-name.foo.bar.de`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.my-name.tls"
            - "traefik.http.routers.my-name.service=my-name"
            - "traefik.http.services.my-name.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

networks:
    traefik:
        external:
            name: traefik
```